# Error showing { expected css(css-lcurlyexpected)

Tags: python, django

All things are going well but my CSS showing this error my
**{% block title %} {% endblock %}**, {% **block body%} {% endblock %}** are good but don't know why **{% block css%} {% endblock %}** doesn't work
[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: CSS is defined in `block css` not `block body`, `This is CSS` is not valid CSS

Comment: I have changed still problem are same sir

Comment: why do you have 2 `title` tags in `basic.html`

Comment: Deleted one still same problem sir

Comment: maybe the top extends needs a semicolon at the end? I had the same error with an import at the top without a semicolon

Answer (score 2):

Regarding this issue you need to change in setting of VS Code as below:

"html.validate.styles": false